# Rowwise Mean in columns contain word except last column

Tags: r, select, dplyr, string-matching

I am trying to get the mean of columns that contain a especific word in name except last column with contain the same word in name, example

```
df <- data.frame( ABC_1 = runif(3),
            ABC_2 = runif(3),
            ABC_3 = runif(3),
            ABC_4 = runif(3) )
```

Here I get the value for the last column that contain word: ABC, in col: max

```
df2=df %>%  
rowwise() %>%
mutate_at(vars(last(contains('ABC'))), funs(max= max(., na.rm = TRUE))) 


      ABC_1 ABC_2 ABC_3 ABC_4   max
      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
    1 0.191 0.486 0.455 0.246 0.246
    2 0.523 0.728 0.812 0.517 0.517
    3 0.134 0.937 0.992 0.899 0.899
```

With the same logic, now I tried to get the mean of all column with name ABC, except last column:

```
df3=df %>%  
rowwise() %>%
mutate_at(vars(last(contains('ABC'))), funs(max= max(., na.rm = TRUE))) %>%
mutate_at(vars(-last(contains('ABC'))), funs(mean= mean(., na.rm = TRUE)))
```

But lamentably I dont get the result expected:

```
      ABC_1 ABC_2 ABC_3 ABC_4   max ABC_1_mean ABC_2_mean ABC_3_mean max_mean
      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>    <dbl>
    1 0.191 0.486 0.455 0.246 0.246      0.191      0.486      0.455    0.246
    2 0.523 0.728 0.812 0.517 0.517      0.523      0.728      0.812    0.517
    3 0.134 0.937 0.992 0.899 0.899      0.134      0.937      0.992    0.899
```

Comment: Well, I am confused: you said you want the mean of the columns containing ABC but except the last one. But in your example, you take the max of this specific last columns. So this logic won't work for what you want, right?

Comment: Well, I mean that I could get the value of the last column with especific name

Comment: Ok, so you need to reverse that logic to get what you want. All the columns but last. @tmfmnk answer seems goot to me. Also: to make your example reproducible, you can use set.seed("the number you want") before running `runif`. More info [there](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/120371/why-doesnt-runif-generate-the-same-result-every-time)

Comment: Yes, the answers of @tmfmnk works great to me too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option could be:

```
df %>%
    mutate(ABC_mean = rowMeans(across(head(starts_with("ABC"), -1))))

      ABC_1     ABC_2     ABC_3     ABC_4  ABC_mean
1 0.5957359 0.7201537 0.1304605 0.1697986 0.4821167
2 0.6865635 0.9463447 0.8447037 0.4149000 0.8258706
3 0.2364415 0.8335135 0.6342009 0.4410836 0.5680520
```